# Using Subset in R

Tags: r, subset

I am new to R and I am trying to find the sizes of subsets.
Namely, I have two columns in my data.frame (BuenosMalos) that I am interested in.

I have columns, Sex (values: masculino/femenino) and Malo(values: 0/1)

And I want to know how many femenino's have Malo value of 0.

I used:

```
bad<-subset(BuenosMalos,sexo=="Femenino", Malo==1)
length(bad)
```

But the value I am getting is both incorrect and illogical.(I double checked it using Excel and the COUNTIFS function).

Would appreciate suggestions on how to do this in R

Comment: `length` is giving you the number of columns - you might want `nrow` instead?  But if you just want to count, then you can do `sum(BuenosMalos$Malo==1)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of how you can do this using `table`:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)

mydf <- data.frame(
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 20, TRUE),
  malo = sample(0:1, 20, TRUE)
)
```

Tabulation:

```
table(mydf)
#    malo
# sex 0 1
#   F 7 4
#   M 5 4
```

Extracting the relevant row/column combination:

```
table(mydf)["F", "1"]
# [1] 4
```

---

As also mentioned in the comments, `length` on a `data.frame` returns the number of columns, not the number of rows. To get that, you would use `nrow`, like this:

```
nrow(with(mydf, mydf[sex == "F" & malo == 1, ]))
# [1] 4
```

---

If you wanted to go the `subset` approach, try:

```
nrow(subset(mydf, sex == "F" & malo == 1))
# [1] 4
```